# The import sun cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, sun

I have a little problem while compiling an Android application with Eclipse.

It says :

```
The import sun cannot be resolved
```

Actually I want to use the `NotImplementedException` Class from the package

```
sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects
```

Do you have any ideas where it come from ?

I have Java 1.7 installed and Eclipse Indigo IDE for Java EE Developers.

Comment: What is your code for importing?

Comment: See also: [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classes in `sun.*` are [not meant to be imported](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html). They are for internal use of the JVM only.

Use [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) instead of `NotImplementedException`.

Answer (score 3):

The `sun.*` packages are not part of the JDK but rather implementations in the Oracle JVM. As you are developing for Android (the dalvik JVM), those packages are not available. Simple as that.