# Eclipse import com.sun canot be resolved in android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I need these libraries in my **android** project. How can I use them?
I get `import com.sun.*, java.awt.*` cannot be resolved in android project

```
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
```

Comment: A simple search found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344654/how-to-add-java-awt-image-package-in-android).

Comment: I dont understand the answer? how to use these libraries in my android project??

Comment: The long and skinny of it is you're not going to be able to use them (awt). The alternative is using Androids own [graphics package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html).

Comment: and what about com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile;? what is the alternative one?

Answer (score 1):

> The classes in `sun.*` are [not meant to be imported](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html). They are for
>   internal use of the JVM only.
>
> Use [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) instead of
>   `NotImplementedException.`

Welcome to StackOverFlow, please next time search your problem before asking the question.

got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12670033/1932105), simple search did it all.